# Solución para error 404 en imágenes locales ASP .Net

Tags: html, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-8.0

Tengo mi etiqueta:

```html
<img src="../Images/ICONO.png" alt="Logo" />
```

pero no me muestra mi imagen en la página gracias al error "Falied to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404()" mi imagen la cargo en el layout, desde ya gracias por su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas aclarar mejor tu duda, ya que es un poco confuso lo que estas diciendo y no se puede saber con certeza cual es el problema. Aunque te recomendaría que revises bien como estas importando porque el problema es que no encuentra dicho icono.

Comment: Gracias!! básicamente es eso, no encuentra el icono y no se por qué, el error que me da en consola del navegador es el ya mencionado

Comment: Quizás tengas que salir un nivel más "../"

Comment: Estuve probando y descubrí que si la imagen la paso a la carpeta wwwroot si la encuentra y la muestra, investigue que esa carpeta actúa como la raíz del proyecto, ahora mi duda es como puedo solucionar eso, cómo puedo acceder a archivos fuera de esa carpeta sin que me presente esos inconvenientes

Comment: Será mejor que cree una carpeta Images dentro del wwwroot para mantener la estructura ordenada